# "Repeating truth too often or being too insistent about it leads to doubt", is there such an effect?

Tags: psychology

I have noticed that when someone repeats something too often or is too insistent about it, I will be more likely to doubt them, even if what they're saying is true.

My thought process might go something like "the repetition and insistence might signal that they're compensating for something".

For example, the acquaintance of a murder victim who constantly claims their innocence even when not being accused would probably trigger some doubt in my mind.

I was wondering if there's a name for that phenomenon if it exists at all.

Comment: I too have noticed such, nice question

Comment: This question was received unfavorable, primarily because it does not showcase any effort towards framing this question within the cognitive sciences. It is based on a personal observation of yours, but not backed up by references to indicate this is a more pervasive observation.